# How to plot lines from a dataframe with column headers as the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I figure I need to do some sort of data sorting/display it differently in order to plot the graph but I'm not sure how. I have tried transposing the data set but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

This is my data after slicing and I need to plot W values as x axis vs the R values as y1, y2, y3, y4 and y5

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'observations': [15, 28, 10, 6, 25],
        'biomass': [94.67, 56.56, 81.33, 26.00, 65.78],
        380: [0.013918, 0.012229, 0.013622, 0.015602, 0.011784],
        390: [0.015578, 0.012762, 0.014548, 0.017856, 0.013304],
        400: [0.016338, 0.014434, 0.014872, 0.019132, 0.014054]}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[14, 17, 9, 5, 24])

data1.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After sampling the dataframe, change the index values to the desired format of `y1 to yn+1`
2. Select the desired columns with [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), which selects all the rows, and the columns from index 2, and then transpose the dataframe with [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

   - The index will be the x-axis, and each column will be a line plot
3. Plot the dataframe with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which plots with `matplotlib` as the backend.

- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
import pandas as pd

# given the sample in the OP, relabel the index values
data1.index = [f'y{i}' for i in range(1, len(data1)+1)]

# display(data1)
    observations  biomass       380       390       400
y1            15    94.67  0.013918  0.015578  0.016338
y2            28    56.56  0.012229  0.012762  0.014434
y3            10    81.33  0.013622  0.014548  0.014872
y4             6    26.00  0.015602  0.017856  0.019132
y5            25    65.78  0.011784  0.013304  0.014054

# select data and transpose
data1 = data1.iloc[:, 2:].T

# display(data1) - Note the difference after selecting columns and transposing
           y1        y2        y3        y4        y5
380  0.013918  0.012229  0.013622  0.015602  0.011784
390  0.015578  0.012762  0.014548  0.017856  0.013304
400  0.016338  0.014434  0.014872  0.019132  0.014054

# plot
ax = data1.plot(xlabel='Wavelength', ylabel='Reflectance', figsize=(10, 5), marker='.', xticks=data1.index.tolist())
ax.legend(title='Sample', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For each graph you need two arrays or lists x and y.

Since x values are the same for every graph you can reuse them. You could get them from the keys of your DataFrame (assuming they are integers) like this:

```
x = [key for key in df.keys() if type(key) == int]
```

Next you need the y values for each graph. You can iterate the rows of a DataFrame with df.iterrows():

```
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()    # create figure and axes
   for index, row in data1[x].iterrows(): 
        ax.plot(x, row)
   plt.show()
```

`data1[x]` returns columns that are in x

`iterrows()`returns tuple of index and row. Row is of type pandas.Series